# Encoding chinese characters works with hotmail but not with gmail or yahoo

Tags: php, character-encoding, imap

i managed to retrieve the email's body in chinese characters  with hotmail via IMAP but with gmail or yahoo it doens't work. I don't know why:

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "info@*******.com", "********");

$email="mail@hotmail.com";

$num_mensaje = imap_search($mbox,"FROM $email");

$body =  imap_fetchbody($mbox,$num_mensaje[0],"1");

$str =  mb_convert_encoding($body,"UTF-8","big5,EUC-CN");
```

Comment: What's in the `$body`?  Is it base64 encoded instead?

Comment: body from yahoo: =E4=BD=A0=E5=A5=BD=C2=A0=C2=A0=E4=BD=A0=E5=A5=BD=E4=BD=A0=E6=80=8E

Comment: body from gmail: U3ViamVjdDog5L2g5aW95L2g5oCOPz8/5L2g5aW95L2g5oCOPz8/YnI+CuS9oOWlvSAgKuS9oOWl

Answer (score 0):

Look at the contents of the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in the email message. It will tell you what format the body of the email is in, which will dictate how you must decode it.

Transfer encodings you will need to support include:

- `7bit`, `8bit`, or `binary`: These formats require no preprocessing.
- `quoted-printable`: Use the [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode) function.
- `base64`: Use [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/base64_decode).

Once you have handled the transfer encoding, THEN you can apply `mb_convert_encoding`.

Comment: i use fetchstructure to see  the Content-Transfer-Encoding and return the same value 0 (UTF-7) for every kind of email (hotmail,gmail,yahoo)  $estrutura = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$num_mensaje[0], FT_UID);
       echo  $estrutura->encoding;

Comment: foreach ($estrutura->parts as $part) {

      if ($part->encoding == 4) {   //yahoo   //gmail
         // inline message. Show number of lines

      $body2 = quoted_printable_decode ($body);

      } elseif ($part->encoding == 3) {  //gmail
        
         
       $body2 = base64_decode($body);

      } elseif ($part->encoding == 1) {   //hotmail
         // an attachment
         
       $body2 = $body;

      }